# Software for Glossing/Tagging and Mapping Patterns in Text

Tags: text-processing, modeling, language

## Pleasantries

I'm an English major temporarily studying at Oxford and I feel my literary/rhetorical analyses and argumentation could use a touch of the 'objectivity,' real or supposed, that computational analysis does readily seem to lend. I know nothing about NLP, and I'm not a linguist. I do, though, have basic knowledge of Ruby, XML, and Python.

## The Question

That said, I'm looking for software/modules/languages that allow me to

1. Input text (well, duh...)
2. Gloss/tag/markup (preferably through a context menu as opposed to actual XML-like tags) text so that I can categorize it by rhetorical/literary device, concept, conjugation...
3. Summarize, visualize, compare, and export results.

Pipe dream or extant product? Please do let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already know some python you could take a look at the Natural Language Toolkit - [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/) - it has a large suite of tools and the ability to customise most of them.

Of your requirements:

1. Input text - *of course*
2. Gloss/tag/markup (preferably through a context menu as opposed to actual XML-like tags) text so that I can categorize it by rhetorical/literary device, concept, conjugation... *Usually performed by tailoring the analysis mechanism rather than manually*
3. Summarize, visualize, compare, and export results. *Yes - it is python so you can do a lot*

Some additional features:

- Free (Libre & FLOSS)
- Cross Platform
- Extensible
- Widely used
- Active support
- For some examples of the sorts of analysis that can be performed there is an [online demo](http://text-processing.com/demo/).